# sql LIKE does not show wanted results to fetch

Tags: php, sql, fetch, sql-like

For an related products part I'm making it does not show the results I want it to show.

This is my code:

```
    // Info current t-shirt. Normally from database
    $name = "T-shirt";
    $description = "Stylish LUFTRAUSERS T-shirt designed by Amon26.";
    $relatedSearch = $name . " " . $description;

    // Query which searches for related items
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE description LIKE '%' :relatedSearch '%' OR name LIKE '%' :relatedSearch '%' LIMIT 5");
    $query -> bindParam("relatedSearch", $relatedSearch, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if($query -> execute()){
        while($related = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            echo "<p style='color:black;'>" . $related->description . "</p></br>";

        }
    }
```

When I replace the bindparam $relatedSearch for $name it does show 5 results. But when I search for $relatedSearch variable it doesn't show anything. It seems that it searches for the full string and nothing matches that. Instead of that I just want it to look for single words in that string

Extra: Screenshot of the database http://puu.sh/eeviJ/133a2de7c9.png

Comment: So I guess the obvious question, is have you verified the string contained in `$relatedSearch` is what you are expecting and that it matches at least 5 rows in the database?

Comment: Yes I want it to search for all "single words" in that string (which contains $title and $description)

Comment: @user3428971 That's not how it works. By saying, look for `%this is an example%` it is looking for a value that contains the string `this is an example`. It doesn't break it up for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the colon in your binding. I would also try structuring your query like this instead.

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_products 
                       WHERE description 
                       LIKE :relatedSearch OR name LIKE :relatedSearch LIMIT 5");
$query -> bindParam(":relatedSearch", '%' . $relatedSearch . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

But, maybe this is more like what you're looking for...

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_products 
                       WHERE description 
                       LIKE :description OR name LIKE :name LIMIT 5");
$query -> bindParam(":description", '%' . $description . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query -> bindParam(":name", '%' . $name . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is usefull for you.

Do not use single quote after `%`.

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE description LIKE '% :relatedSearch %' OR name LIKE '% :relatedSearch %' LIMIT 5");
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not show any results after changing that

Comment: why you used : after %

Comment: for pdo to bindparam that variable